# handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100のエラー出力

Tags: python, python3, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver

サイズの小さいwebページだとエラー文が出力されずにスクリーンショットを撮ることが出来るのですが、サイズの大きいwebサイトを撮ろうとするとエラー文が出力され続け、一枚撮るのに三分ほどかかります。この解消方法をずっと調べているのですが、厳しいです。わかる方いらしたら何卒宜しくお願い致します。

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import os 
import datetime


#ヘッドレス実行　※全画面用
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

driver.get("https://パズドラ.gamewith.jp/")
#driver.get("https://laboratory.kazuuu.net/get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-using-python/")
#driver.get("https://pad.gungho.jp/member/")
#driver.get("https://www.post.japanpost.jp/zipcode/dl/oogaki-zip.html")

#保存する画像ファイル名
fname = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

#スクショ保存ディレクトリが存在しなければ生成
if os.path.isdir(os.getcwd()+"\\ss") == False:
    os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+"\\ss")

#ウインドウサイズをWebサイトに合わせて変更　※全画面用
width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollWidth;")
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
driver.set_window_size(width,height)

#スクショをPNG形式で保存
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(os.getcwd() + "\\ss\\" + fname + ".png")
```

エラー文

```
[0901/150328.629:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0901/150332.492:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -103
[0901/150333.053:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0901/150335.737:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0901/150337.184:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -103
[0901/150339.141:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -103
[0901/150339.593:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(968)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

Comment: この辺の記事あたりが参考になるかもしれませんね。[【python】スクレイピングでのエラー原因について](https://teratail.com/questions/188516), [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(1158)\] handshake failed with ChromeDriver Chrome browser and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37883759/9014308), [handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202](https://qiita.com/t_o01/items/0eabc33358dcbe7e8ab2#%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0-2), [Selenium ssl_client_socket_impl.cc handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65755603/9014308), [handshake failed; returned -1, ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63466426/9014308)

Comment: このIssue [Dev Tools closes unexpectedly after a minute or two of use #7182](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/7182) が類似かもしれませんね。116版から発生しだしたとかベータ版だと発生しないとか何かしたらベータ版でも発生したとか書かれているようです。試しに115版以前の古い版にしてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 上記コメントに紹介した記事から辿るとこんな記事がありました。こちらを試してみては？ [Selenium ssl_client_socket_impl.cc handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65755603/9014308), [How to ignore ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1061)\] handshake failed in selenium c# ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53735756/9014308)